# Why do I get the "could not find the controller" error?

Tags: services, javascript

I'm trying to setup [DrupalGap](http://drupalgap.org/) with [Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) following this [tutorial](http://tylerfrankenstein.com/code/build-mobile-app-sell-products-with-drupal), but I get this error:

> 404 not found: could not find the controller.

I've manually confirmed Services are set up properly with Advanced REST client (Chrome), with this [instructions](https://www.drupal.org/node/2015065). All seems OK; the endpoint/resource is operating and I receive a *200 OK* response, but when I try to test the application from admin/config/services/drupalgap, I always get this error.

I use Services frequently and I can confirm It's working good on this site. I also verified DrupalGap is working too.

What could it be?

Comment: Using the Network tab in your browser's development tools, what is the URL that is throwing the 404 error?

Comment: This is the secuence: 301 GET drupalgap?q=services/session/token;  200 GET token;  301 POST /?q=drupalgap/system/connect.json;  404 GET connect.json.  The last URL requested, when I get 404 error is: .../drupalgap/system/connect.json

Comment: A 301 is a redirect, it sounds like you have the Global Redirect module enabled. See this note for details: https://www.drupal.org/node/1927336

Comment: Thanks. It worked great. I have applied the latest patch and I have followed your instructions: https://www.drupal.org/node/1438584#comment-11738043

Comment: Wonderful, I've added an answer with some more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `301` is a redirect, so it sounds like you have the [Global Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect) module enabled. See this issue for details: https://www.drupal.org/node/1927336

The patch allows you to declare paths that should be ignored by the Global Redirect module so it doesn't hijack Service calls to your Drupal site. You'll input something like this into the configuration text area once the patch has been applied:

`drupalgap/*`